# Is it possible to manually wipe the memory of a GtkEntry using the GTK3 library?

Tags: c, security, memory-management, gtk, gtk3

I have a pointer to a GtkEntry that contains a password that's input by the user. I want to call Libsodium's secure memset function on the memory block once I'm done with the GtkEntry. Here's an invalid example that outlines what I'm trying to do:

```
GtkEntry *entry = GTK_ENTRY(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "passwordEntry"));

...

const gchar *password = gtk_entry_get_text(entry);
gint length = gtk_entry_get_text_length(entry);

...

sodium_memzero(password, length);   // Undefined behaviour
```

The API specifies for `gtk_entry_get_text()`:

> This string points to internally allocated storage in the widget and
>   must not be freed, modified or stored.

So I'm wondering if this would otherwise be possible to do without invoking undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GtkEntry` uses `GtkEntryBuffer` for managing text. The text stored in `GtkEntryBuffer` is zerod when it (or the associated `GtkEntry`) is freed (That is, on `g_object_unref`)
See its source code [1](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/gtk-3-24/gtk/gtkentrybuffer.c#L267) and [2](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/gtk-3-24/gtk/gtkentrybuffer.c#L94).

If you want to use a better secure buffer for saving passwords you can try [GcrSecureEntryBuffer](https://developer.gnome.org/gcr/unstable/GcrSecureEntryBuffer.html). but that requires your project to depend on [gcr](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gcr).

Or if you truely want to use libsodium, you can subclass `GtkEntryBuffer` and do memory management on your own, and use that buffer to create a `GtkEntry`.